# issue with IFF and Multiple cascading Split in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, split, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, iif

I am getting error for the below,

```
=IIF(Fields!ParentObjectType.Value !="Approval Request",Split(Split(Fields!CT_CaptionURL.Value,"f =").GetValue(1),"Target").GetValue(0),Split(Split(Fields!CT_CaptionURL.Value,"f=").GetValue(1),"target").GetValue(0))
```

### Got the below error
The Value expression for the field ‘URL’ contains an error: [BC30203] Identifier expected.

### The definition of the report '' is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Replace != with <> in your expression

Comment: This is also not working   =IIF(Fields!ParentObjectType.Value<>"Approval Request",(Split(Split(Fields!CT_CaptionURL.Value,"href =").GetValue(1).ToString()," Target").GetValue(0).ToString()),(Split(Split(Fields!CT_CaptionURL.Value,"f=").GetValue(1).ToString(),"target").GetValue(0).ToString()))

Comment: Fields!ParentObjectType.Value this returns an <A href> tag...

Comment: The (initial) cause of this error is  != operator. If you still have error issues please provide sample data.

Comment: do all the values in CT_CaptionURL ALWAYS contain the pairs of strings you are splitting by? If any do not contain ieth `f=` or `f =` or now you seem to have changed the question `href =` ? If not then the first part of the expression will fail. Please EDIT your question as the code you posted in the comment no longer matches the code in the question (href was never in the original question)